# Need Clarity on Bulk import methods in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, import-products

I have seen that we have import/export option for bulk products. My question is what is the difference between 1.import product 2. export product and DataFlow-Profiles.

In Dataflow profiles also, import all products and export all product options are there. Why there are two kind of import/export options available and what is the difference?

[image]

Please refer the image,and my question is  what is the difference between option 1 and option 2?

when we click the option2 we are getting below window.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: Import Export**

when you export products using this option, the header columns name in csv will be same as attribute codes. you cannot change. also when you importing products using this option, you have to use exact attribute code as csv columns which are created in the system.

you can skip or filter product export as per screenshot below, but with option 1 you have to repeat this actions again when you need to export same file in future.

Option 1 only supports csv format for import and export

[image]

**Option 2: Dataflow profiles**

Dataflow provides custom column names in import export. Also it's supports csv, txt and XML formats. You can see more features form below screenshot

[image]

Comment: I can see that in both the cases we need to use exact attribute name, But need why two ways available, Need clarity on this.

Comment: In 2nd option you can define your own columns name in csv. E.g. if you are selling your products in Amazon you needs to provide csv in Amazon important format. In Magento you have sku as identifier. Amazon expect 'item id' as your sku. If you will export csv from first option you always needs to do manually work every time. By using option 2 you can map those fields that magento sku = Item id in csv. Also you can export only selected columns. Everytime you just need to click on download.

Comment: @ManikandanArunachalam : did you found my answer is useful ?

Comment: useful , but i could not feel why magento keep two ways of importing/exporing bulk product.Maybe explaining the difference between these two will help me.